# Difference between `git fetch` and `git push` for local fast-forwarding

Tags: git

I've been trying to solve the problem of how to "fast forward" local branches without checking them out. (Or to be more clear: I want all my local branches to be on the same commits as their tracked remote branches, but without having to checkout each one into the working copy.)

I've come across two options which both seem to produce the desired outcome, but unintuitively using opposite commands:

`git fetch . origin/mybranch:mybranch`

and

`git push . origin/mybranch:mybranch`

**(For those coming here from search engine, note the dot! Which means, "the 'remote' is the local repository.")**

The explanations I've seen are opaque: The first "fetches" the local origin/mybranch content into mybranch. But what are the consequences of that?

The second "pushes" the local origin/mybranch content into mybranch. What are the consequences of that?

Reading the documentation on these two commands does indeed make it seem like they'd both do the job, but I'm curious about subtleties or differences in failure cases.

Why would a person choose one over the other, or is there a third way that solves the problem more directly than either?

Thanks.

Comment: Fast-forwarding moves a branch (pointer) to a new commit. Fetch and push do neither of this to the local repo. (afaik)

Comment: _"The first "fetches" the local origin/mybranch content into mybranch"_ what makes you think this?

Comment: fetch and push both update the position of a tag, just usually over the network. E.g. if the server's 'master' tag is on a0351bca, and I fetch, then my local 'origin/master' tag moves to a0351bca (after transferring all the appropriate commits). By specifying `.` as my remote, these changes happen between local branches, instead of over the network.

Comment: (At least, this is my understanding. As I said, it's fairly opaque! But, you can try the commands given, they do indeed appear to "fast forward" a non-checked-out branch.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting hack :)

The default setup seems to update the reflog in both cases, `fetch` updates it with a more explicit message :

```
# After using 'git push ...' and 'git fetch ...' once :
$ git reflog branch
0dc3ff2 branch@{0}: fetch . origin/branch:branch: fast-forward  # when using 'git fetch'
5d0749b branch@{1}: push                                        # when using 'git push'
```

The weirder parts I can see are :

- git will call `git upload-pack` using `.` (but I'm pretty sure there is an optimization which turns this into a noop when git detects it actually is the same object repository on the same filesystem),
- `git push` will trigger pre-push hooks, while `git fetch`, to my knowledge, doesn't trigger any hook,
- `fetch` and `pull` may trigger a repack and a garbage collection

but I don't see any of these steps failing (well : the pre-push hook could prevent updating your ref).

(set `GIT_TRACE=xx` to have more insights into what happens)

Other than that : in both cases, git just checks wether `branch` is an ancestor of `origin/branch`, and updates `branch` if ok, and prints an error message if not.

---

If you want to have a script that updates a branch if and only if it is a fast forward to its remote, you can combine `git merge-base --is-ancestor` and `git update-ref` :

```
if git merge-base --is-ancestor branch origin/branch; then
    # git update-ref :
    #   you need to provide a '-m' to have a message in the reflog,
    #   you need to provide the fully qualified branch ref : refs/heads/...
    git update-ref -m "merge refs/remotes/origin/branch: Fast-forward" \
           refs/heads/branch origin/branch
else
    echo "*** non fast-forward" >&2
    exit 1    # you can set a non zero exit code on failure
fi
```

but this is a bit convoluted,
so all in all your `git fetch / git pull` hack seems like a pretty efficient way to go through all the regular checks already handled by git.

Comment: "git just checks wether branch is an ancestor of origin/branch" -- this really was my biggest concern. I'm using this mostly as a convencience, so I'm okay with it failing, I just don't want it to, well, "unexpectedly succeed" and put my repo into an unexpected state or lose work.

Comment: The other thing to be aware of is that the refspec for both fetch and push is "src:dst", i.e., source first, then destination. When you fetch to yourself, both src and dst are both local, which—once you've gotten used to "src local on fetch, but dst not" and "dst local on push, but src not" anyway—winds up feeling creepy somehow. At least, it does to me. :-)